# Why IE doesn't support my CSS positioning

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, browser-support

I positioned links on one image which has 3 buttons, (something like [this](http://www.templatetuning.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/dare-to-share2.jpg)).

The positioning works with Firefox and Chrom, but with my "favorite" IE(11).. well.. I see the link on the image as an invisible very small character. If I was a user, I wouldn't notice it and think the link isn't working.

I can't publish my real code, but I will change the names in it.

HTML (there is a "lps" class div before this code):

```
<img src="http://example.ag/nts/images/category/subcat/btns.jpg" style="margin-top: 25px;
margin-bottom: 35px;">

<div class="promotioncontent">
    <a class="how modal_link" href="#">&nbsp;</a>

    <div class="term" style="display: none;">
        <div class="termcontent">
            <div class="termheader"><h3>WORK</h3><a href="#" class="a_close"></a>
            </div>

                <div class="termtext">
                    <img src="http://example.ag/nts/images/category/subcat/work.jpg">
                    <a class="openprize opennext" href="#"></a>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <a class="prize modal_link" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
        <div class="term" style="display: none;">
            <div class="termcontent">
                <div class="termheader"><h3> TABLES</h3><a href="#" class="a_close"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="termtext">
                    <img src="http://example.ag/nts/images/category/subcat/tables.jpg">
                    <a class="openfaq opennext" href="#"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a class="faqs modal_link" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
        <div class="term" style="display: none;">
            <div class="termcontent">
                <div class="termheader"><h3>FAQs</h3><a href="#" class="a_close"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="termtext">
                    <img src="http://example.ag/nts/images/category/subcat/FAQ.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Only the relevant CSS:

```
.lps a.how {
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: 189px;
}

.lps a.modal_link {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 70px;
    display: block;
    width: 233px;
    height: 76px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

What can be the cause of the problem and how can I fix it without ruining it on the Firefox and Chrome browsers?

Comment: Why are you not using sprite? Your link leads to sprite image and every element has same `background-image` but with different `background-position`

Comment: @Justinas It's an option but I prefer not to change the code too much for now.

Comment: You better make more complicated code instead of "Best practice"? You are building house that is intended to collapse and still continue, because you have already started...

Comment: Well, this is a website that someone gave me to work on, and in general, it's built horrible, and I don't have access to most of the files of this website, not ever to the FTP. 
I tried a few ways to fix the positioning, and nothing works, so I think that I will start working on sprite. 
My problem with this now is that it uses JS that's activated when clicking on object inside objects inside objects and I don't have access to edit nothing using js. unless I do one my own, that wont be efficient and bad SEO. 
I am guessing that it's a familiar problem and people know how to solve it.

Comment: @Justinas Hi, In the end, instead of the image I used a div with background-image, and it worked. 

Thank you very much :) !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Answer to accept*

Instead of placing invincible elements over sprite image, use `background-image` as that sprite and just change [`background-position`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp) for each element. That way you can put any size spacing between elements, no matter of spaces between sprite images.

Answer (score 0):

## use a different stylesheet for IE support without ruining other browsers layout in head tag

```
            <!--[if IE]>
            According to the conditional comment this is IE<br />
            <![endif]-->
            <!--[if IE 6]>
            According to the conditional comment this is IE 6<br />
            <![endif]-->
            <!--[if IE 7]>

            <![endif]-->
            <!--[if IE 8]>
            According to the conditional comment this is IE 8<br />
            <![endif]-->
            <!--[if IE 9]>
            According to the conditional comment this is IE 9<br />
            <![endif]-->


            <!--[if gte IE 8]>
            <link href="ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


            <![endif]-->




            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            According to the conditional comment this is IE lower than 9<br />
            <![endif]-->
            <!--[if lte IE 7]>
            According to the conditional comment this is IE lower or equal to 7<br />
            <![endif]-->
            <!--[if gt IE 6]>
            According to the conditional comment this is IE greater than 6<br />
            <![endif]-->
            <!--[if !IE]> -->
            According to the conditional comment this is not IE 5-9<br />
            <!-- <![endif]-->
            </p>
            <!--[if gte IE 8]>
            <style>
            body
            {
            background:Red;
            }
            </style>
            <![endif]-->

            <!--[if gte IE 7]>
            <script>
              alert("Congratulations! You are running Internet Explorer 7 or a later version of Internet Explorer.");
            </script>
            <p>Thank you for closing the message box.</p>
            <![endif]-->
```