# CSS not working with IE 9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have the below HTML and CSS. The CSS works fine in firefox but the color does not get applied in IE 9. I have specified the doctype as  in xhtml file. How do i make it work with IE9?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="j_idt19:j_idt20" class="ui-tabmenu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <ul class="ui-tabmenu-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
        <li class="ui-tabmenuitem ui-state-default ui-state-active ui-corner-top" aria-expanded="true" role="tab">
            <a id="j_idt19:homeTab" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all tabMenuDefaultCls" href="/XXX.xhtml?i=0" tabindex="-1">
                <span class="ui-menuitem-text"> … </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-tabmenuitem ui-state-default ui-corner-top" aria-expanded="false" role="tab"> … </li>
        <li class="ui-tabmenuitem ui-state-default ui-corner-top" aria-expanded="false" role="tab"> … </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.ui-state-active li {
    background-color: #F85A5A !important;
}


li[aria-expanded="false"] {
    background-color: #9975FC !important;
}

li[aria-expanded="true"] {
    background-color: #F85A5A !important;
}

.tabMenuDefaultCls {
    /* background-color: #9975FC; */
}
```

**Answer:**

Solved the issue by giving more precedence to a css class as,

```
li[aria-expanded="false"] a {
        background-color: #9975FC !important;
}

li[aria-expanded="true"] a {
        background-color: #F85A5A !important;
}
```

Add a tag to the css class to take precedence.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add this `MetaTag` after `<head>` tag :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer suraj gave here will be relevant for you: 
[Why IE doesn't support my CSS positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25521854/why-ie-doesnt-support-my-css-positioning)

If it cheers you up, on IE11 it works fine..

http://jsfiddle.net/cg6jLnax/

```
e
```

Comment: i use JSF and the css class of JSF framework overrides my css atrribute selector class.

Comment: What's tat "e" ? Try to be clear in ur answer.@Hatul

Comment: @Jayaprasad I cant post jsfiddle links without code inside an answer.